# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

I'm geting an **"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection."** error that doesn't allow me to perform this simple request above:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const GITHUB_AUTH_ACCESSTOKEN_URL = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token'
  const CLIENT_ID = '123'
  const CLIENT_SECRET = '456'


    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: GITHUB_AUTH_ACCESSTOKEN_URL,
        data: {
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
        }
      })
    .then(function (response) {
      alert('Sucess ' + JSON.stringify(response))
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      alert('Error ' + JSON.stringify(error))
    })

});
```

I can't understand why this is happening because I'm properly handling the error with the ".catch()" method. How can I perform this request correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alert doesn't exists natively in nodejs, so the error is probably coming from the `.catch`

try instead this code:

```
 axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: GITHUB_AUTH_ACCESSTOKEN_URL,
        data: {
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
        }
      })
    .then(function ({data}) {
      console.log('Success ' + JSON.stringify(data))
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error ' + error.message)
    })
```

if you want bit more "modern" way

```
// notice the async () =>
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const GITHUB_AUTH_ACCESSTOKEN_URL = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token'
    const CLIENT_ID = '123'
    const CLIENT_SECRET = '456'
    try {
        const { data } = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: GITHUB_AUTH_ACCESSTOKEN_URL,
            data: {
                client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
            }
        })
        console.log(data)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`alert` is a host method, which can be found in browser environment, thus it doesn't exist in node.js.

1. it first throws error in `.then`
2. gets caught in `catch`,
3. get's thrown again now within `catch`,
4. since there is nothing to catch the last `catch` it's handled by global promise rejection handler.

To try to handle the situation start with changing every alert with `console.log` and `console.error` respectively:

```js
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: GITHUB_AUTH_ACCESSTOKEN_URL,
        data: {
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
        }
      })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log('Success ' + JSON.stringify(response))
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error('Error ' + error.message)
    })
```